# tracking outlook emails using microsoft graph api

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I would like to create an application to find out how much time taken to reply to an email. ie, when an email arrived, need to get the time and when I replied to that email need to not that time and find how much time i spend on replying that email.

for this purpose I have used Microsoft graph API v1.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages -> can read all the mails. but it contain all incoming and outgoing emails.
i need only list of incoming emails first and then reply time based on the same.

Answer (score 0):

To get messages in a specific folder in the user's mailbox:

```
GET /me/mailFolders/{id}/messages
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}/messages
```

To get more Optional query parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters

Comment: I already have this API and have listed all user emails. but what my exact requirement is: 
1. list only the first or main message in a conversation.
2. list all emails on another page based on the conversation I selected, along with that need to calculate the time between an incoming email and particular mail's reply.

the tracking is to find my team's average response time for an incoming email.